# install ROS in fedora

Tags: ros, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I refer to 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Fedora' install ros, but not a successful install, an error is as follows:
Bootstrapping ROS build

```
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros', 'ros_comm']                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/Yz/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110924-091802
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros', 'ros_comm'] to:
['rosdep', 'rosemacs', 'roscreate', 'rosmake', 'rosunit', 'rosbash', 'rosboost_cfg', 'rosclean', 'rospack', 'rosbuild', 'mk', 'roslib', 'roslang', 'test_roslib', 'test_rospack', 'test_roscreate', 'test_rosdep', 'test_rosmake', 'roslisp', 'rospy', 'roscpp', 'roscpp_serialization', 'roscpp_traits', 'rosout', 'topic_tools', 'rosbag', 'rosconsole', 'rosparam', 'roslaunch', 'rosnode', 'rosmsg', 'rosmaster', 'rosgraph', 'rosbagmigration', 'rostopic', 'rostest', 'rosservice', 'std_msgs', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'std_srvs', 'roscore_migration_rules', 'message_filters', 'roswtf', 'cpp_common', 'xmlrpcpp', 'rostime', 'test_rostopic', 'test_crosspackage', 'test_rosnode', 'test_roswtf', 'perf_roscpp', 'test_rostest', 'test_ros', 'test_roscpp', 'test_rosbag', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_rosparam', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_rosservice', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_rostime', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_rospy']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main
    self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps
    r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.yc = YamlCache(self.osi.get_name(), self.osi.get_version(), self.osi.get_os().installers)
AttributeError: Fedora instance has no attribute 'installers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main
    self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps
    r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/opt/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.yc = YamlCache(self.osi.get_name(), self.osi.get_version(), self.osi.get_os().installers)
AttributeError: Fedora instance has no attribute 'installers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.20', 'rosinstall')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 599, in <module>
    sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 590, in rosinstall_main
    subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(options.path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 504, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /opt/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11298/install-ros-in-fedora/) by [Yayi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1115/yayi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I tried to install ROS on Fedora 15 (both Diamondback and Electric, I think, you try Electric) too.  There is bug report on this problem ([Bug 3616](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3616)), and some days ago it was closed with patch. I think, you should try it.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yayi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1115/yayi/) on 2011-09-24**:
thanks , that's ok